# Postfix: How do I create a mail@example.com account when "mail" is an existing system account?

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix mail server and I'd like to set up mail@example.com. However, the system user `mail` already exists on the system. Is there a way to set up some kind of aliasing to workaround the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use virtual users so postfix compares incoming emails to the virtual list and not system users. This also allows you to tell postfix the inbox location on the hard drive where to store the messages either in unix or maildir/ format.

On this [postfix docs page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) search for each of the following to get you going in the right direction...

```
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_mailbox_base
virtual_minimum_uid
virtual_uid_maps
virtual_gid_maps
virtual_mailbox_domains
virtual_mailbox_maps
virtual_alias_maps
```

If you need config help with the above i can give more details. You can set up either flat files (easiest) or SQL (harder).

Comment: Crap. That's the only way, huh? I don't want to have to convert all users over to virtual users. No way to set up a virtual user for that one "mail" user?

Comment: Yes, you can run a mix of real users and virtual users. Another option of using all real users and just sending email to mail@example.com to another user like root look in /etc/aliases. After edits to the aliases file run command newaliases for it to take effect.

Comment: Just found this: https://serverfault.com/a/659847/398214 too. OK, I will see if I can hammer this out. Thanks!